# wwv_flow_data_parser.parse moves value to wrong cell

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex, xlsx, oracle-apex-19.1

I have some code where the parse function of a xlsx-File in apex gives a wrong result.

```
Row1 empty
A2: AZ
B2: Text
```

[image]

Rest empty.

```
-- Put file into Database first (named testfall_short_neu.xlsx)
with src as (
select id, daten,datei_name
from wpr02_datei
where datei_name = 'testfall_short_neu.xlsx' )
select line_number, col001,col002
                           from src, table( 
                                      wwv_flow_data_parser.parse(
                                          p_content         => src.daten,
                                          p_file_name       => src.datei_name,
                                          p_xlsx_sheet_name => 'sheet1.xml'));
```

Result:

```
Line_NUMBER COL001  COL002
          1 null    Text
          2 AZ      null
```

Should be:

```
Line_NUMBER COL001  COL002
          1 null    null
          2 AZ      Text
```

Any hints why this is happening? Bug on support.oracle.com opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this seems indeed to be a bug with APEX_DATA_PARSER, which manifests when the *first* row of the XLSX is empty.

Can you send me the number of the "Bug on support.oracle.com opened" ?

Best regards

-Carsten

Comment: SR 3-21663765901

Comment: Hi Thomas,

thank you for the service request (ticket) number. Since Support did not file a bug yet, I did so - bug number 30589873 ("SQL WORKSHOP DATA LOADING AND APEX_DATA_PARSER RETURN VALUES IN WRONG ROW FOR XLSX WITH EMPTY FIRST ROW") tracks this issue. It's already fixed for the next APEX version.

Please follow-up with Support, if the issue is urgent for you and you need a patch for 19.1 or 19.2 ...

Best regards

-Carsten

Comment: I only have to import data from 140 xlsx sheets one-time. So with knowing the error it's possible to write a workaround or fix the sheets manually. So no need for me to wait for the fix.